# Can someone make an ad banner for Android Enthusiasts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I'm not much of a graphic artist, but I would like to include a banner ad for Android Enthusiasts in my Android app, Car Dashboard. I get about 10k eyeballs a day, so maybe a few will of my users will come and check us out.

Could anyone make a good looking banner ad?  It's the standard size for banners ads on Android: 320 x 50 px so others can use it too.  You can find examples of my other ads [here](http://bryandenny.com/software/Android/default.aspx) (refresh for new ad).

Also, any suggestions of which page it should re-direct to? Just http://android.stackexchange.com?

Thanks!

Comment: Good idea. Probably best if anyone posting banners here also explicitly says whether or not they'd be happy for other app developers to use their banner too, so that this post could be used as a general resource for AE banner ads?

Comment: can you send me your email to jin@stackexchange.com and I'll send something your way. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Android Ad]

Sent this to you via email. Also posting here in case other people may use for on their sites/apps.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!  Here's what it looks like in the app for any who are wondering: http://i.imgur.com/Xx0q4.png